# Using Flow typing with the map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

Here's some simple React layout code:

```
<div>
  {users.map(user => <AddUser user={user} key={user.id} />)}
</div>
```

I'm simply calling N instances of an `AddUser` component and passing it some values.  Here's how the `User` object is defined:

```
export type User = {
  id: number,
  email: string,
  role: string,
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string
}
```

Over the `{user}` instance I'm getting this error:

> Cannot create `AddUser` element because  null or undefined [1] is
>   incompatible with  `User` [2] in property `user`.
>   and over the `id` property of `{user.id}` I'm getting this error:
>   Cannot get `user.id` because property `id` is missing in  null or undefined [1].

How should I correct this?

UPDATE:

In the interest of completeness, here's the working solution of the code proposed by @Mike Abeln:

```
<div>
  {users.map(user => {
    return (user !== undefined && user !== null)
    ? <AddUser user={user} key={user.id} classes={classes} state={fleetCustomerState} dispatch={dispatch} />
    : null
  })}
</div>
```

Comment: How is users typed?

Comment: The `user !== undefined && user !== null` check should not be necessary if the type of `users` is `Array<User>`, but since you haven't given us that type, this question is hard to answer. The error implies that maybe you instead has `Array<?User>`? Please provide all of the types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what `flow` is telling you here is that you should check to make sure that `<AddUser />` is not `null` or `undefined`

**Return the `AddUser` component after checking against `null` and `undefined`:**

```
<div>
  {users.map(user => {
    return (user !== undefined && user !== null) ? <AddUser user={user} key={user.id} /> : null
  })}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  I'll give it a try.

Is there any other way to do it, for example, to somehow define `users` such that there can't be any null values in the array ... which actually is the case.

Comment: You're welcome, my experience with flow is pretty limited, but as far as I know there isn't. Flow wants you to be very explicit and in most cases that leads to more verbose code - but it's for good reason.